# Clarify tags "organ" and "pipe-organ"

Tags: discussion

Purists maintain that these mean exactly the same thing.  If it ain't got pipes, it ain't an organ.

Practically, we already have a few dozen questions about the Hammond B3, properly and usefully tagged "organ."

Can the explanations for these tags clarify that somehow?  Tag pipe-organ excludes Hammonds; organ includes; prefer the more precise pipe-organ for instruments found in cathedrals and vintage theatres?

Comment: Currently, [organ](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organ) seems to *exclude* Hammonds: *"A large musical instrument having ranks of tuned pipes sounded by air from a windchest..."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest having [pipe-organ](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pipe-organ) and [electric-organ](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-organ), the latter encompassing Hammonds, Farfisas, Vox etc. as well as questions about Leslie cabinets. The current [organ](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organ) should be removed, the currently 75 questions re-tagged with either of the special ones.

Pipe organs are very different from electric ones in playing technique, sound and associated musical genres, so I definitely don't fint it good to just throw them together. Probably most electric-organ questions will be about Hammonds, and the other ones don't really warrant a tag of themselves.

Arguably, the Leslie cab is an effect in its own right that can be used also with non-organ instruments, but it's so strongly associated with the Hammond that it's not worthwhile to have an own [leslie](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leslie) tag.

Not sure about reed organs. They probably don't warrant an own tag either, although there are again significant differences in playing technique. It probably ok to just classify these as [pipe-organ](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pipe-organ) (after all pipe organs generally have reed registers), or perhaps it should be rather [acoustic-organ](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustic-organ) or [wind-organ](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wind-organ)? Alternatively, keep it [pipe-organ](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pipe-organ) plus add [harmonium](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmonium).

If a question really is applicable to both pipe organs and electric ones, it can have both tags, or more likely it should simply be tagged [keyboard](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard).

Comment: I'm for the pipe-organ and electric-organ tag. The one thing we'd need to figure out is what to do with the current tag

Comment: @Dom edited. Let's [burn](https://youtu.be/ydlrfKbExcs?t=340) [tag:organ].

Comment: I can definitely get behind pipe- and electric-organ, and I've seen enough harmonium questions that I certainly wouldn't object to adding that as well. (cc: @Dom)

Comment: Seems strange to have a guitar tag but not an organ tag.

Comment: @ToddWilcox well, the strange thing is that pipe organs and electric organs are in practice so different that there's hardly any overlap between them, or rather, that the overlap must be so inspecific that it falls right to the parent `keyboard` tag. By contrast, the way guitars are used is much more of a continuum, and many questions would apply to both acoustic and electric guitars, but are still clearly guitar-specific and not to any other `string-instrument`s.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not an expert on organs, but I feel the simplest path is to only have one tag. Until we really need both, I suggest we just have the [organ](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organ) tag and clean up the tag wiki except.  A number of pipe organ question seem to also have the organ tag anyway.

We don't tend to have tags for each variant of an instrument for example we don't  have an upright piano tag vs a grand piano tag. The difference in a hammond organ vs a  theater organ is bigger than those I understand, but if we don't need to distinguish then we shouldn't need it.

If there are any specific question or questions that need this distinction we should go over those in more depth.

Comment: Yes, let's make it a single `organ` tag.  Any objections?

Comment: I'll start to remove the pipe organ tag from straggling questions.